# ArrayList class .add error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am currently learning about arrays and the weblesson from my class is teaching me about the ArrayList class. I tried to make my own array to try it out, but when I followed the format the weblesson showed me, I get a compiler error that reads: "no suitable method found for add(java.lang.String)". While highlighting the ".add".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class String
{
    ArrayList <String> myArrayList;
    public void arrayTest()
    {
        ArrayList <String> names = new ArrayList <String> ();

        names.add("John");
        names.add("Smith");
        names.add("Matt");

        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer your next question about NullPointerException: you created one `ArrayList` and stored it in `names` reference, then you filled it with data, but in next step you are trying to read data from uninitialized `myArrayList` reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is hiding `java.lang.String` so there is a type mismatch between the argument used for the `add` method and your custom `String` class. Rename it to something else other than `String`

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that your class is also called `String`. I'm guessing the generic type of your `ArrayList` is that and not the Java `String`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you are naming your class as `String`, which will make the compiler get confused because there already exist a built-in `String`.

**What can you do?**

- Rename your class, to something different:

  ```
  public class StringTest
  ```
- Or use the fully qualified class name (which I wouldn't recommend):

  ```
  ArrayList <java.lang.String> names = new ArrayList <java.lang.String> ();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are naming your class String, the String in

```
ArrayList < String > names
```

is referring to your self-defined class type. Therefore, only the 'String' objects that you defined can be added to the ArrayList, not the actual Java Strings. To correct this, **name your class something else.**